# django return variable back to user

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to add a tool to my site that hashes a serial number, and as such I don't require a model for this particular part of the site. What I wanted to do is use if statements in the template to remove the form fields and submit button and display the hash on the same page, however, I can't figure out how to get my result back to the template. The form I have created is the most basic with just two fields.

here is my view:

```
def voice_search_view(request):
    form = VoiceSearchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoiceSearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            hw_number = form.cleaned_data['hw_number']
            ca_serial = form.cleaned_data['ca_serial']

        if len(ca_serial) == 16:
            prehash = hw_number + ca_serial[5:-1] + 'cc_voice'
            territory = 'DE'
        elif len(ca_serial) == 11:
            prehash = hw_number + ca_serial[:-1] + 'cc_voice'
            territory = 'UKIT'

        print(hw_number)
        print(ca_serial)
        print(prehash)
        sha_sig = hashlib.sha256(prehash.encode()).hexdigest()
        print(sha_sig)
        return redirect('/voice_search/')
    return render(request, 'voice_search.html', {'form': form})
```

how can I return the sha_sig back to the user, in an ideal world, I would just add it to the context, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Bearing in mind that I am not even using any css for this, it's a very quick temporary tool. What would be the easiest way to return this value to the user?

Comment: You can use context. Just return the data like `return render(request, <template_name>, context={"form": form, "your_data": data})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just edit your file like this?

```
def voice_search_view(request):
    form = VoiceSearchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoiceSearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            hw_number = form.cleaned_data['hw_number']
            ca_serial = form.cleaned_data['ca_serial']

        if len(ca_serial) == 16:
            prehash = hw_number + ca_serial[5:-1] + 'cc_voice'
            territory = 'DE'
        elif len(ca_serial) == 11:
            prehash = hw_number + ca_serial[:-1] + 'cc_voice'
            territory = 'UKIT'

        print(hw_number)
        print(ca_serial)
        print(prehash)
        sha_sig = hashlib.sha256(prehash.encode()).hexdigest()
        print(sha_sig)
            return render(request, 'voice_search.html', context = {'form': form,'sha_sih':sha_sig})
    return render(request, 'voice_search.html', {'form': form})
```

And then change your template to check if `sha_sig` is a defined variable and if it is, output the HTML code as well as the `sha_sig` information.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Ironically, I did do something similar to this, but a spelling mistake of my own variable made me think I was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Glad to be of help.